# Consultar precio de una tabla de rango de precios

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Cuando cargo la página del producto tengo un selector de cantidades que quiero pedir. En base a eso necesito consultar una tabla relacionada donde almaceno los posibles rangos de precios, por ejemplo, 100 o + el producto vale 1.90€, 500 o + el producto vale 1.80€.

**Tabla rango_precios**

| id | producto_id | cantidad | precio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 100 | 1.80 |
| 3 | 3 | 500 | 1.75 |

Entonces cuando voy cambiando cantidades del producto, lo guardo en una variable de jQuery. Supongo que tengo que hacer una consulta con AJAX a la tabla relacionada, pero no se como consultar esto. ¿alguna sugerencia?. No busco la solución solo que me guien.

En el caso de tener dos cifras seria fácil, pero con una única cifra no se por donde tirar.

**Petición AJAX**

```
var id = producto_id;
var url = '/mi-cuenta/productos/client/obtener_precio';
$.ajax({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
  type: "get",
  url: url,
  data: {
    "id": id,
    "cantidad": cantidad_inicio
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

**En el controlador - Laravel**

```
public function obtenerPrecio(Request $request)
{
  dd($request);
}
```

*Aquí es donde ya no se como proceder a la consulta en la tabla `rango_precios`*

No si es posible hacer, buscar por la cantidad que sea igual o mayor que la que traigo pero menor que la `siguiente`?

---

Estoy probando así pero sin éxito:

```
$precio = Rango_precios::where('producto_id', $request->id)->where('cantidad', '>=', $valorActual)
          ->where('cantidad', '<=', function ($query) use ($valorActual) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('MIN(cantidad)'))
                ->from('rango_precios')
                ->where('cantidad', '>', $valorActual);
            })
            ->get();

            return $precio;
```

**Pongo ejemplo para ser más claro:**

Si cantidad es 150, me tiene que tomar el precio de 100
Si cantidad es 499, me tiene que tomar el precio de 100
Si cantidad es 500, me tiene que tomar el precio de 500
Si cantidad es 501 o más me tiene que tomar el último precio de cantidad más alta, en este caso 500
En esta ocasión solo hay dos rangos de precio tal como he puesto en la tabla arriba.

Comment: La tabla está en una bd sql o dónde? Un .csv? O qué?

Comment: En una tabla sql llamada `rango_precios` he actualizado mi pregunta

Comment: Esto es un tema de SQL como tal, más no de javascript o jquery. Agrega el tag del dbms que estás usando.

Comment: Hola @Sal fue un error de tipeo

Comment: Hola @Miguel. Para este tipo de escenario, mi consejo es que tengas guardado en la vista todos los rangos de precios. Considero que no es conveniente hacer una llamada ajax por cada vez que modifiquen la cantidad. Además... ¿cuantas "ofertas por cantidad" vas a tener? No creo que se justifique. Y la solución es "_buscar el primer registro donde la cantidad es mayor o igual y ordenado de forma ascendente por cantidad_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo fácil habría sido que en cada fila estuviera el rango inferior y superior, pero digamos que eso no se puede tocar.

Entonces la consulta en SQL es esta:

```
SELECT precio
 FROM Rango_precios 
 where producto_id = 3 and cantidad<=500
 order by cantidad desc
 limit 1
```

*Tu te encargarás de pasarlo al ORM que estas usando*

En tu escenario la cantidad mínima de un producto es 100, voy a suponer que eso es correcto. De lo contrario aparece un problema de borde cuando la cantidad requerida es menor a 100, esto se soluciona agregando un nuevo registro que comience con cantidad 1

---

Sobre el tema del Ajax, tal como dice @Marcos en su comentario, yo los dejaría en la vista, dentro de un atributo, en un array de arrays, con un par `[cantidad,valor]`, algo así lo haría

Supongamos que tenemos 3 inputs, y solo podemos variar la cantidad:

```js
Array.prototype.Max = function(fn){
  return this.toSorted((a,b)=> fn(b) - fn(a)).at(0);
}
Array.prototype.Min = function(fn){
  return this.toSorted((a,b)=> fn(a) - fn(b)).at(0);
}


document.querySelectorAll(".cantidad").forEach(el =>{
  //Esto es para setear la cantidad con los valores iniciales, que corresponden al minimo
  const [precioEl,totalEl] = getElements(el.dataset.id);
  precioEl.rangos = JSON.parse(precioEl.dataset.rangos);
  
  const valorDefault = precioEl.rangos.Min(a=>a[0]);
  
  el.value = el.min = valorDefault[0];
  
  precioEl.value=valorDefault[1].toFixed(2);;
  totalEl.value= (valorDefault[1] * valorDefault[0]).toFixed(2);
  
  el.addEventListener("input", changecantidad);
}

);

function changecantidad(){
   const [precioEl,totalEl] = getElements(event.target.dataset.id);
   const cantidad = event.target.valueAsNumber;
   
   if(isNaN(cantidad) || cantidad < Number(event.target.min)){
      precioEl.value = "-";
      totalEl.value = "-";
      return;
   }
   
   const valor = precioEl.rangos.filter(a=>a[0]<=cantidad).Max(a=>a[0])[1];
   precioEl.value=valor.toFixed(2);
   totalEl.value= (valor * cantidad).toFixed(2);

}


function getElements(id){
  return [document.querySelector(`.precio[data-id='${id}']`),
  document.querySelector(`.total[data-id='${id}']`)];
}
```

```html
<input
  data-id="3"
  type="number"
  class="cantidad">

<input 
  data-id="3"
  data-rangos="[[100,1.80],[500,1.75]]"
  class="precio"
  readonly>
  
<input 
  data-id="3"
  class="total"
  readonly>
```

Comment: Tenes razón! Se me acomodo el tornillo :D

Comment: @Marcos Les pasa hasta los mejores xD